# Generic Code in Python with Selenium for Reading value from UI

Tags: python, selenium

I am using generic code to reduce the duplicate code to read value from UI if any additional suggestion please let me know.

`readvaluefromUI(objidtype, objid)` function works as mentioned below.

It takes the `objidtype` ---> e.g. `(ID,CSS_SELECTOR,NAME etc)`.

It takes the `objid` ---> actual id of object and retrun the text value of object.

```
def readvaluefromUI(objidtype, objid):
    try:
        if objidtype == "ID":
            element =  driver.find_element_by_id(objid).text
            return(element)
        elif objidtype == "CSS_SELECTOR":
            element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(objid).text
            return(element)
        elif objidtype == "CLASS_NAME":
            element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(objid).text
        return(element)   
    elif objidtype == "XPATH":
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(objid).text
        return(element)
    elif objidtype == "TAGNAME":
        element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(objid).text
        return(element)
    elif objidtype == "NAME":
        element = driver.find_elements_by_name(objid).text
        return(element)
except:
    Throwable(traceback)
```

It return the object which you can use in your calling method.
e.g.
`readvaluefromUI(ID, "firstname")`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @cody my question is is any latest object type I can include to make it generic or any better way of reading value from UI?

Comment: @GhostCat : Apologies for my mistake, I am new user and learning here. For sure I am not going to repeat this again. Sorry Again

Comment: Never mind, we are all here to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your generic method in the following way : (note : this is not any latest object type, this is already available)

```
def readvaluefromUI(objidtype, objid):
   element = driver.find_element(objidtype,objid)
   return element.text
```

in this case you need to pass your objidtype of type By (for example : By.ID / By.XPATH etc.,) . For this you need to import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```